# How can I display GIMP's logo in the taskbar instead of a thumbnail?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, gimp

Whenever an image is opened in GIMP, the Windows taskbar icon changes from the standard Wilber head into a thumbnail of the current image.

I sometimes get confused trying to locate GIMP on a crowded taskbar, as I don't have a consistent icon to look for. I'm not the only one with this issue, as there was a bug report submitted for this a few years ago in 2013. ([Bug #707932](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=707932))

**How can I display GIMP's logo in the taskbar instead of using the current image as a thumbnail?**

[image: Comparison of taskbar icon]

Comment: Anyone know if there's an easy way to disable the thumbnail these days? I find it super frustrating that I can't instantly recognise GIMP in my taskbar because it uses thumbnails instead of GIMP Logo

Answer (score 0):

Pinning the icon to the taskbar fixed that problem for me.

(I'm using version 2.10.8 on Win 10).

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnails in the task bar icon have been removed as of Gimp version 2.99.8. Currently that version is only available via the development branch of Gimp. If you want to use it, download it here: https://www.gimp.org/downloads/devel/. Note that the development version may experience more bugs/crashes than the standard stable version.

Source: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/7029

Answer (score -1):

For GIMP 2.10.2:

```
>gimp-2.10.exe
00000000000E91B2:0F->90
00000000000E91B3:84->E9

00000000004E9170 | 41 56                    | push r14                                            | taskbar icon setting routine
00000000004E9172 | 41 55                    | push r13                                            |
00000000004E9174 | 41 54                    | push r12                                            |
00000000004E9176 | 55                       | push rbp                                            |
00000000004E9177 | 57                       | push rdi                                            |
00000000004E9178 | 56                       | push rsi                                            |
00000000004E9179 | 53                       | push rbx                                            |
00000000004E917A | 48 83 EC 70              | sub rsp,70                                          |
00000000004E917E | 0F 29 74 24 60           | movaps xmmword ptr ss:[rsp+60],xmm6                 |
00000000004E9183 | 48 89 CB                 | mov rbx,rcx                                         |
00000000004E9186 | E8 95 4E FF FF           | call gimp-2.10.4DE020                               |
00000000004E918B | 48 89 D9                 | mov rcx,rbx                                         |
00000000004E918E | 48 89 C2                 | mov rdx,rax                                         |
00000000004E9191 | E8 2A FA 30 00           | call <gimp-2.10.g_type_check_instance_cast>         |
00000000004E9196 | 48 8B 48 78              | mov rcx,qword ptr ds:[rax+78]                       |
00000000004E919A | 48 89 C3                 | mov rbx,rax                                         |
00000000004E919D | E8 DE 26 FF FF           | call gimp-2.10.4DB880                               |
00000000004E91A2 | C7 83 28 02 00 00 00 00  | mov dword ptr ds:[rbx+228],0                        |
00000000004E91AC | 48 85 C0                 | test rax,rax                                        |
00000000004E91AF | 48 89 C7                 | mov rdi,rax                                         |
00000000004E91B2 | 0F 84 E9 01 00 00        | je gimp-2.10.4E93A1                                 | <-- jump to normal icon branch
00000000004E91B8 | 48 8B 4B 78              | mov rcx,qword ptr ds:[rbx+78]                       | composited icon branch begins here
00000000004E91BC | E8 4F 26 FF FF           | call gimp-2.10.4DB810                               |
00000000004E91C1 | 48 89 F9                 | mov rcx,rdi                                         |
00000000004E91C4 | 48 89 C5                 | mov rbp,rax                                         |
00000000004E91C7 | E8 C4 2B 23 00           | call gimp-2.10.71BD90                               |
00000000004E91CC | 48 89 F9                 | mov rcx,rdi                                         |
00000000004E91CF | 89 C6                    | mov esi,eax                                         |
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you elaborate on this? Perhaps **edit your answer** to explain what you are describing and *why* you are suggesting to edit those bytes in the executable. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Hope the disassembly of this part explains it a bit. Disabling that distracting "feature" will take another three years, the most probably, so we have no other choice than hacking it while waiting, save recompiling it from the source.

Comment: I like this answer but it's only valid for that one version. This post might quickly become meaningless. Maybe showing where this happens in the source code would be more reliable than executable code which could change wildly between versions.

Comment: Gimp is open source though...